# Syntax error while compiling bson in chicaogboss

Tags: compilation, erlang, chicagoboss

We upgraded chicagoboss which has the dependency of 'bson'. When we compile the chicagoboss using `./rebar update-deps compile`. While compiling the chicagoboss it throws syntax error. 
But basically we pull it from 'HEAD'. I'm not sure if that is the good idea though.

```
Pulling bson from {git,"git://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang","HEAD"}
Cloning into 'bson'...
```

Here is the compile error:

```
$./rebar update-deps compile
...
...
...
==> erlando (compile)
Compiled src/cut.erl
Compiled src/do.erl
Compiled src/monad.erl
Compiled src/monad_plus.erl
Compiled src/identity_m.erl
Compiled src/test.erl
Compiled src/error_m.erl
Compiled src/error_t.erl
Compiled src/list_m.erl
Compiled src/maybe_m.erl
Compiled src/import_as.erl
Compiled src/omega_m.erl
Compiled src/state_t.erl
==> aleppo (compile)
src/aleppo_parser.yrl: Warning: conflicts: 1 shift/reduce, 0 reduce/reduce
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/aleppo/src/aleppo_parser.yrl:none: Warning: conflicts: 1 shift/reduce, 0 reduce/reduce
Compiled src/aleppo_parser.yrl
Compiled src/aleppo_parser.erl
Compiled src/aleppo.erl
==> medici (compile)
Compiled src/medici.erl
Compiled src/medici_port_srv.erl
Compiled src/principe_table.erl
Compiled src/medici_native_conn.erl
Compiled src/medici_native_controller.erl
Compiled src/medici_conn_sup.erl
Compiled src/medici_sup.erl
Compiled src/medici_conn.erl
Compiled src/medici_port_sup.erl
Compiled src/medici_app.erl
Compiled src/medici_controller.erl
Compiled src/principe.erl
==> bson (compile)
Compiling workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl failed:
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:40: syntax error before: '{'
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:55: syntax error before: '{'
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:4: function get_map/1 undefined
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:33: function get_fields/2 undefined
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:36: spec for undefined function bson_binary:get_map/1
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:36: type map() undefined
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:78: illegal guard expression
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:92: function get_map/1 undefined
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:86: function get_field/4 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:142: function get_field/2 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:153: function get_string/1 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:172: function get_array/2 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:179: function get_values/3 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:194: function get_binary/1 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:207: function get_closure/1 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:219: function get_unixtime/1 is unused
workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson/src/bson_binary.erl:228: function get_oid/1 is unused
ERROR: compile failed while processing workspace/ChicagoBoss/deps/bson: rebar_abort
make: *** [all] Error 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to compile new bson with maps on machine with old erlang. Which version do you have?

Comment: @P_A - Okay, I'm using `Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) `. But for now we can't upgrade it. What's the way to get old version of `erlang-bson`?

Comment: You can specify working version of `bson` in `rebar.config` before `boss_db` dependency. As I can see tag `v0.2` is ok.

Comment: @P_A  - Yep, Thanks for your efforts. I pulled it from an old commit.like this:
` {git,"git://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang","old-commit-hash"}`. you can comment your suggestion as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @Vetal4eg - Yes, Plz have a look at above comment. 
`{git,"git://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang","old-commit-hash"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of the problem is that `mongodb-erlang` `ce9bf77902` from BossDB `v0.8.15` (current ChickagoBoss) uses `HEAD` version of `bson` which is incompatible with Erlang/OTP < 17 now.

You can specify working version of `bson` in rebar.config before `boss_db` dependency. As I can see tag `v0.2` is ok for `R16B03-1`.